# Delay ternary operator from checking React State till useEffect Hook finishes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, conditional-operator, use-effect

I hope I'm phrasing my question the right way. Here is what I have going on.

I have a ternary operator set up like the code below. It checks for the existence of state and opens a Modal form if the state does not exist.

```
   { !selectPet && selectClient ?
                <Modal>
                    <Form>
                       <form stuff/>
                    </Form>
                </Modal> 
              : null 
   }
```

selectPet is set in the useEffect hook like this.

```
function clientsPets() {
        if (selectClient !== undefined) {
            API.getClientPets(selectClient._id)
                .then(res => {
                    if (res.length > 0) {
                        setSelectPet(res) // Right here is where the selectPet is being set
                        setActivePet(res[0])
                        API.getPetSessionsByPetId(res[0]._id)
                            .then(res => setTrainingSessions(res))
                            .catch(err => console.log(err))
                    } else {
                        return
                    }
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err))
        } else { history.push("/") }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        clientsPets()
    }, [])
```

What I am having trouble with is when the page first loads the Modal is displayed for less than a second before the useEffect finishes. Logically Im not sure how to fix this. Could I set some sort of interval before checking the selectPet state or is there a better way to resolve this?

Comment: By your issue, it looks like you have provided some initial value to your  selectClient, please make it null and your issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the initial state values for `selectPet` and `selectClient`? If you don't want the modal to appear until your API calls are done and those state values have been updated, just make sure the initial values are set such that the ternary will skip to the "else" block and render `null` instead of the modal.

Bear in mind, since the first condition in the ternary is `!selectPet`, either the initial value of `selectPet` must be "truthy", or `selectClient`'s initial value must be falsy, in order to skip to the "else" block of the ternary.

Comment: Awesome @Ethin Lipkind that was a simple fix thanks. I dont know what I was thinking when I set that one up. I should have been handling it in terms of true and false in stead of checking for existence of a state.

Answer (score 0):

You need a state item saying whether you have the information for the modal. At the moment you're showing it based purely on `!selectPet && selectClient`, where from your code `selectClient` is an object.

So for instance:

```
const [clientInfo, setClientInfo] = useState(null);
```

and then

```
{!selectPet && clientInfo ?
    <Modal>...</Modal>
}
```

using `clientInfo` in the `Modal`.

Call `setClientInfo(/*...*/)` when you have the client info from the ajax call that the modal needs (which probably means making `clientsPets` return a promise of the information).

Comment: Thanks for the reply I ended up following what Ethan said above because I saw it first. But again thanks for the answer to the question.